# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in localhost\tourist\getPlaces.php on line 37

Tags: php

I am trying to get **JSON** response from server but it's giving me

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in
>   localhost\tourist\getPlaces.php on line 37

my **init.php** is working.

```
      <?php
require "init.php";

function getCategories(){
   // $db = new DbConnect();
    // array for json response
    $response = array();
    $response["places"] = array();

    // Mysql select query
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM places");
    if($result === FALSE) {
    die(mysql_error("error message for the user")); 

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        // temporary array to create single category
        $tmp = array();
        $tmp["id"] = $row['place_id'];
        $tmp["type"] = $row['type'];
        $tmp["thumbnail"] = $row['thumbnail'];
        $tmp["name"] = $row['name'];
        $tmp["city"] = $row['city'];
        $tmp["description"] = $row['description'];

        // push category to final json array
        array_push($response["places"], $tmp);
    }

    // keeping response header to json
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    // echoing json result
    echo json_encode($response);
}

getCategories();
?>
```

Comment: Would be lovely if you could point out which line 37 is.. Not counting it :)

Comment: However a quick glance.. you are missing a `}` you've opened 3 closed 2.

Comment: `if($result === FALSE) {die(mysql_error("error message for the user"));` missed `}` there

Comment: i've tried to change the code to

Comment: now it's giving me <b>Warning</b>:  mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in <b>
{"places":[]}  @Anant

Comment: @NukhbaArshad  simple stop using `mysql_*`. use `mysqli_*` OR `PDO`.thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a closing `}`.

Change

```
if($result === FALSE) {
    die(mysql_error("error message for the user"));
```

To

```
if($result === FALSE) {
    die(mysql_error("error message for the user")); 
}
```